# Path in assets Symfony2.4

Tags: symfony, assets

Good morning.

I have a problem with load css and js in my page.

I have Apache2, php5.4.12, win 7x64

My source:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/cleverfinancemain/style/main.css') }}" />
```

If route localhost/web/app.php => page has

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/web/web/bundles/cleverfinancemain/style/main.css" />
```

If route localhost/web/app_dev.php => page has

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/web/bundles/cleverfinancemain/style/main.css" />
```

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run `php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug` for production environment to generate asset files.

Besides, consider using `web/` folder as DocumentRoot. In this case, your application would be `localhost/app.php` (this is how it should be)

Comment: Great! I set web/ folder as DocumentRoot. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Remove your cache and check it once.